# Run sideloaded WPF Core 3.0 app from command line

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, msix

I've run into a problem while publishing a WPF Core 3.0 app. I created a Windows Application Packaging Project in my solution and then published the WPF app as sideloaded. It was published correctly and I can run it without any problems. However, now I need to start the sideloaded WPF app from another application (WinForms) programmatically with line arguments. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an app execution alias extension for your packaged app. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#alias) and [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/07/05/command-line-activation-universal-windows-apps/#IPYxRXoGBiJBCz4P.97) for more information.

```
<Package
  xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap3">
    <Applications>
        <Application>
            <Extensions>
                <uap3:Extension
                Category="windows.appExecutionAlias"
                Executable="exes\launcher.exe"
                EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
                    <uap3:AppExecutionAlias>
                        <desktop:ExecutionAlias Alias="Contoso.exe" />
                    </uap3:AppExecutionAlias>
                </uap3:Extension>
            </Extensions>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually already found that, now I'm having problems with mentioned command line arguments, but I'll start a new thread for that.